# Do not return row if name= xyz with count=0

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I don't want to return on my select table for Name = XYZ with count = zero.

```
            +------+-------+--------+
            | Name | count | Number |
            +------+-------+--------+
            | XYZ  |     0 |      1 |
            | ABC  |    12 |     56 |
            | YYYY |     0 |      1 |
            | DDD  |     0 |     56 |
            | XYZ  |    14 |     58 |
            +------+-------+--------+
```

Result:

```
            +------+-------+--------+
            | Name | count | Number |
            +------+-------+--------+
            |
            | ABC  |    12 |     56 |
            | YYYY |     0 |      1 |
            | DDD  |     0 |     56 |
            | XYZ  |    14 |     58 |
            +------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter out with a `where` clause. A direct translation of your requirement is:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not (name = 'XYZ' and cnt = 0)
```

You can also express this `or` (assuming that the columns are not nullable):

```
where name <> 'XYZ' or cnt <> 0
```

Note: `count` is a language keyword, hence a poor choice for a column name. I renamed it to `cnt` in the query. Same goes for `number`.